# Create Android server local repository for specific tag

Tags: android, repository, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I would like to create a local server for Android branch android-4.3_r1.1
I follow this thread:
[Cloning Android sources to a local repository server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136789/cloning-android-sources-to-a-local-repository-server)

But I couldn't do the same thing for specific tag,
How can it be done ?

I would like to have a server, and then from the client do some work and push it to the server, so other client can do a sync and see my commits ...

On the server side this is what I did:
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest --mirror
repo sync

On the client side:
repo init -u git-server/android/platform/manifest.git/ -b android-4.3_r1.1
repo sync

I get many of some kind of these errors:
fatal: 'git-server/android/device/ti/panda' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

And all the process is failed ... (error: Exited sync due to fetch errors)

I would like a client AOSP working on android-4.3_r1.1 then do some changes and commit them to the git server.

Comment: The method described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136789/cloning-android-sources-to-a-local-repository-server works fine for replicating tags to a local server. Please be more specific about the problems you're having.

Comment: It works only on the latest branch ... I would like to clone a specific branch

Comment: Ah, yes. Upon careful reading I note that the question I linked to is somewhat outdated. But now that your question is clear so I'll write up a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `repo init --mirror -u $URL/platform/manifest` method is sane, but you'll only sync the gits listed in the manifest in question (the master branch, in this example). So, while all gits that *are* synced will contain all branches and tags needed, the manifest itself doesn't include all gits so subsequent attempts to initialize workspaces based on the created mirror will fail if the manifest branch you've chosen to sync points to gits not included in the master branch's manifest.

The AOSP team has set up special manifest, mirror/manifest, that isn't useful for building anything but lists all gits from all branches and therefore is highly useful for mirroring. In other words, initialize your mirror like this:

```
repo init --mirror -u https://android.googlesource.com/mirror/manifest
```

See the AOSP [Downloading the Source](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html#using-a-local-mirror) documentation.

Comment: I did your suggestion, (running the above command on the server). Now on the client I did the following: repo init -u /home/omri/git-server/android.git/platform/manifest.git/ -b android-4.3_r1.1 and then I did:repo sync bionic (I got bionic) then start a git branch using repo start bionic-devel . and edit some files .... commit them in my local repository but when I wanted to push them git says that Everything is up-to-date I don't understand why, and I would like to push my changes from the client to the server, so other people may see my changes ... thanks

Comment: @omri-c: If my answer worked, please accept it. Your follow-up question is a totally different issue so please open a new question for it.