# Setup mirror repo from overseas server to local server

Tags: git, repository, mirror

Our project involves 5 developers in China and 3 developers in U.S.  The server machine in China is considered the master machine.  I want to setup a mirror of the repo from China server to U.S. server such that our local developers can `repo sync` much faster.  Right now a `repo init / sync` from China server took 5 hours.

As an example, assume the China server is called `server1.china.com` and the U.S. server is called `server2.usa.com`.

The project is pulled from China server using the command:

```
repo init -u ssh://server1.china.com/projectA/standard.git -b release17
repo sync
```

I want to be able to setup a local mirror such that pulling the project becomes:

```
repo init -u ssh://server2.usa.com/projectA/standard.git -b release 17
repo sync
```

I would expect to also need a cron job to run periodically to pull latest changes from server1 to server2 after the initial setup.

I have seen discussions of using `git clone --mirror` but not quite sure it will give exactly what I needed.

Thanks

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for one of the other stack exchange forums, as it is not about programming

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136789/cloning-android-sources-to-a-local-repository-server.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `repo init --mirror`, from `repo init -h`:

```
--mirror            create a replica of the remote repositories rather
                    than a client working directory
```

After you have created it you can keep it up to date with `repo sync`.

Comment: After doing this, I had to modify the `.repo/manifests/default.xml` file, as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136789/cloning-android-sources-to-a-local-repository-server)